# One word for a person you meet while travelling

Tags: single-word-requests

I understand 'co-passenger' could be a term that can be used for a person i'm travelling with. But when it comes to a more poetic connotation, what word can i use?

E.g. The **co-passenger** i met in that phase of my life, we still share the same ride sometimes.

It could mean more like a fellow being on Earth. So, i have ruled out words like partner or co-inhabitant.

Suggestions and corrections are most welcome.

Comment: ***fellow traveler***, as in *the fellowship of the ring*.

Comment: I suggest ’co-passenger' is a term you will never hear used by any native speaker of English. Doubtless, anyone who believes otherwise will be able to show several examples.
The real terms would be ‘fellow traveller” for a stranger met en-route, “travelling companion” for one who’s only role is thus or “companion” for a friend with whom you happen to be travelling.
Your title and details seem to have hugely different meanings but that, or poetry, changes what?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ‘travelling companion’. It means ‘someone who accompanies you on your journey’.

There is a story with this title by Hans Christian Anderson:

http://hca.gilead.org.il/travelng.html